# What is the difference between getAllFailureExceptions() and getFailureExceptions() methods of Spring Batch JobExecution class?

Tags: java, spring-batch

What is the difference between `getAllFailureExceptions()`  and `getFailureExceptions()` methods of Spring Batch `JobExecution` class? What is the right one to use for a generic `JobExecutionListener` that logs job exceptions to a DB?

From what I gathered, a job is just a collection of steps. So then shouldn't getting the failure exceptions always involve getting all the failure exceptions from the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source, it looks like the difference is it includes the failure exceptions of the StepExecutions

[spring-batch/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecution.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecution.java)

Comment: Yes, I took a look at the source. Why would a job have exceptions outside of those in the StepExecutions? Isn't a job just a bunch of steps?

Comment: Looks like no more answers here. I am using `getAllFailureException()` to get all the exceptions. I'm still not sure why would anyone ever use `getFailureExceptions()`

Comment: sorry, not familiar enough to answer. suggest poking in debugger... thanks for accepting my non-answer anyway ;)

Comment: I used `getFailureExceptions()` in  `StepExecutionListener` implementation. Here you only get this available `List<Throwable> exceptions = stepExecution.getFailureExceptions()`